# React Native Permission not working for Camera and Record

Tags: react-native, webrtc

I am using React-Native, I keep getting this error when using WEBRTC in my project, can anyone tell me where I am going wrong

CODE:

```
    import React, {useEffect, useState, useCallback} from 'react';
    import {View, StyleSheet, Alert, PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
    import {Text} from 'react-native-paper';
    import {Button} from 'react-native-paper';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
    import {TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';

    import {useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';

    import InCallManager from 'react-native-incall-manager';

    import {
      RTCPeerConnection,
      RTCIceCandidate,
      RTCSessionDescription,
      RTCView,
      MediaStream,
      MediaStreamTrack,
      mediaDevices,
      registerGlobals,
    } from 'react-native-webrtc';

    async function requestCameraPermission() {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
          {
            title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
            message:
              'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
              'so you can take awesome pictures.',
            buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            buttonPositive: 'OK',
          },
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log('You can use the camera');
        } else {
          console.log('Camera permission denied');
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }
    }


    export default function CallScreen({navigation, ...props}) {
      requestCameraPermission();
      let name;
      let connectedUser;
      const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
      const [socketActive, setSocketActive] = useState(false);
      const [calling, setCalling] = useState(false);
      // Video Scrs
      const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState({toURL: () => null});
      const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState({toURL: () => null});
      const [conn, setConn] = useState(new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080'));
      const [yourConn, setYourConn] = useState(
        //change the config as you need
        new RTCPeerConnection({
          iceServers: [
            {
              urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',  
            }, {
              urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',    
            }, {
              urls: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',    
            }

          ],
        }),
      );
      const [offer, setOffer] = useState(null);

      const [callToUsername, setCallToUsername] = useState(null);

      useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
          AsyncStorage.getItem('userId').then(id => {
            console.log(id);
            if (id) {
              setUserId(id);
            } else {
              setUserId('');
              navigation.push('Login');
            }
          });
        }, [userId]),
      );

      useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
          title: 'Your ID - ' + userId,
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button mode="text" onPress={onLogout} style={{paddingRight: 10}}>
              Logout
            </Button>
          ),
        });
      }, [userId]);

      /**
       * Calling Stuff
       */

      useEffect(() => {
        if (socketActive && userId.length > 0) {
          try {
            InCallManager.start({media: 'audio'});
            InCallManager.setForceSpeakerphoneOn(true);
            InCallManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
            InCallManager.requestRecordPermission();
            InCallManager.requestCameraPermission();
          

          } catch (err) {
            console.log('InApp Caller ---------------------->', err);
          }

          console.log(InCallManager);

          send({
            type: 'login',
            name: userId,
          });
        }
      }, [socketActive, userId]);

      const onLogin = () => {};

      useEffect(() => {
        /**
         *
         * Sockets Signalling
         */
        conn.onopen = () => {
          console.log('Connected to the signaling server');
          setSocketActive(true);
        };
        //when we got a message from a signaling server
        conn.onmessage = msg => {
          let data;
          if (msg.data === 'Hello world') {
            data = {};
          } else {
            data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
            console.log('Data --------------------->', data);
            switch (data.type) {
              case 'login':
                console.log('Login');
                break;
              //when somebody wants to call us
              case 'offer':
                handleOffer(data.offer, data.name);
                console.log('Offer');
                break;
              case 'answer':
                handleAnswer(data.answer);
                console.log('Answer');
                break;
              //when a remote peer sends an ice candidate to us
              case 'candidate':
                handleCandidate(data.candidate);
                console.log('Candidate');
                break;
              case 'leave':
                handleLeave();
                console.log('Leave');
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
          }
        };
        conn.onerror = function(err) {
          console.log('Got error', err);
        };
        /**
         * Socjket Signalling Ends
         */

        let isFront = false;
        mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(sourceInfos => {
          let videoSourceId;
          for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
            const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
            if (
              sourceInfo.kind == 'videoinput' &&
              sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? 'front' : 'environment')
            ) {
              videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
            }
          }
          mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({
              audio: true,
              video: {
                mandatory: {
                  minWidth: 500, // Provide your own width, height and frame rate here
                  minHeight: 300,
                  minFrameRate: 30,
                },
                facingMode: isFront ? 'user' : 'environment',
                optional: videoSourceId ? [{sourceId: videoSourceId}] : [],
              },
            })
            .then(stream => {
              // Got stream!
              setLocalStream(stream);

              // setup stream listening
              yourConn.addStream(stream);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              // Log error
            });
        });

        yourConn.onaddstream = event => {
          console.log('On Add Stream', event);
          setRemoteStream(event.stream);
        };

        // Setup ice handling
        yourConn.onicecandidate = event => {
          if (event.candidate) {
            send({
              type: 'candidate',
              candidate: event.candidate,
            });
          }
        };
      }, []);

      const send = message => {
        //attach the other peer username to our messages
        if (connectedUser) {
          message.name = connectedUser;
          console.log('Connected iser in end----------', message);
        }

        conn.send(JSON.stringify(message));
      };

      const onCall = () => {
        setCalling(true);

        connectedUser = callToUsername;
        console.log('Caling to', callToUsername);
        // create an offer

        yourConn.createOffer().then(offer => {
          yourConn.setLocalDescription(offer).then(() => {
            console.log('Sending Ofer');
            console.log(offer);
            send({
              type: 'offer',
              offer: offer,
            });
            // Send pc.localDescription to peer
          });
        });
      };

      //when somebody sends us an offer
      const handleOffer = async (offer, name) => {
        console.log(name + ' is calling you.');

        console.log('Accepting Call===========>', offer);
        connectedUser = name;

        try {
          await yourConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));

          const answer = await yourConn.createAnswer();

          await yourConn.setLocalDescription(answer);
          send({
            type: 'answer',
            answer: answer,
          });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('Offerr Error', err);
        }
      };

      //when we got an answer from a remote user
      const handleAnswer = answer => {
        yourConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer));
      };

      //when we got an ice candidate from a remote user
      const handleCandidate = candidate => {
        setCalling(false);
        console.log('Candidate ----------------->', candidate);
        yourConn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
      };

      //hang up
      const hangUp = () => {
        send({
          type: 'leave',
        });

        handleLeave();
      };

      const handleLeave = () => {
        connectedUser = null;
        setRemoteStream({toURL: () => null});

        yourConn.close();
        // yourConn.onicecandidate = null;
        // yourConn.onaddstream = null;
      };

      const onLogout = () => {
        // hangUp();

        AsyncStorage.removeItem('userId').then(res => {
          navigation.push('Login');
        });
      };

      const acceptCall = async () => {
        console.log('Accepting Call===========>', offer);
        connectedUser = offer.name;

        try {
          await yourConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));

          const answer = await yourConn.createAnswer();

          await yourConn.setLocalDescription(answer);

          send({
            type: 'answer',
            answer: answer,
          });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('Offerr Error', err);
        }
      };
      const rejectCall = async () => {
        send({
          type: 'leave',
        });
        ``;
        setOffer(null);

        handleLeave();
      };

      /**
       * Calling Stuff Ends
       */

      return (
        <View style={styles.root}>
          <View style={styles.inputField}>
            <TextInput
              label="Enter Friends Id"
              mode="outlined"
              style={{marginBottom: 7}}
              onChangeText={text => setCallToUsername(text)}
            />
            <Button
              mode="contained"
              onPress={onCall}
              loading={calling}
              //   style={styles.btn}
              contentStyle={styles.btnContent}
              disabled={!(socketActive && userId.length > 0)}>
              Call
            </Button>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.videoContainer}>
            <View style={[styles.videos, styles.localVideos]}>
              <Text>Your Video</Text>
              <RTCView streamURL={localStream.toURL()} style={styles.localVideo} />
            </View>
            <View style={[styles.videos, styles.remoteVideos]}>
              <Text>Friends Video</Text>
              <RTCView
                streamURL={remoteStream.toURL()}
                style={styles.remoteVideo}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      root: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
      },
      inputField: {
        marginBottom: 10,
        flexDirection: 'column',
      },
      videoContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        minHeight: 450,
      },
      videos: {
        width: '100%',
        flex: 1,
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden',

        borderRadius: 6,
      },
      localVideos: {
        height: 100,
        marginBottom: 10,
      },
      remoteVideos: {
        height: 400,
      },
      localVideo: {
        backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
      },
      remoteVideo: {
        backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
      },
    });
```

Error:

```
        [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_InCallManager.checkCameraPermission')]
    at node_modules\react-native-incall-manager\index.js:137:4 in InCallManager#checkCameraPermission
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:189:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
    at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
    at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
    at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:188:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:211:38 in enqueue
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:238:8 in exports.async
    at [native code]:null in checkCameraPermission
    at node_modules\react-native-incall-manager\index.js:22:8 in InCallManager#constructor
    at http://192.168.1.102:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:168267:34 in <unknown>
    at node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:321:11 in loadModuleImplementation
    at http://192.168.1.102:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:167304:68 in <unknown>
    at node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:321:11 in loadModuleImplementation
    at http://192.168.1.102:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:134166:54 in <unknown>
    at node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:321:11 in loadModuleImplementation
    at node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js:3:0 in <global>
    at node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:321:11 in loadModuleImplementation
    at node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:201:44 in guardedLoadModule
    at http://192.168.1.102:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:170463:3 in global code

    [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_InCallManager.checkRecordPermission')]
    at node_modules\react-native-incall-manager\index.js:123:4 in InCallManager#checkRecordPermission
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:189:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
    at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
    at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
    at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:188:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:211:38 in enqueue
    at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:238:8 in exports.async
    at [native code]:null in checkRecordPermission
    at node_modules\react-native-incall-manager\index.js:21:13 in InCallManager#constructor
    at http://192.168.1.102:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:168267:34 in <unknown>
    at node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:321:11 in loadModuleImplementation
    at http://192.168.1.102:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:167304:68 in <unknown>
    at node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:321:11 in loadModuleImplementation
    at http://192.168.1.102:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:134166:54 in <unknown>
    at node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:321:11 in loadModuleImplementation
    at node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js:3:0 in <global>
    at node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:321:11 in loadModuleImplementation
    at node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:201:44 in guardedLoadModule
    at http://192.168.1.102:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:170463:3 in global code
```

The error above is a warning, but once i type in the login value and hit the button i get this error:

```
                You can use the camera
            Error [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'WebRTCModule.peerConnectionInit')]

            TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'WebRTCModule.peerConnectionInit')

            This error is located at:
                in CallScreen (at SceneView.tsx:122)
                in StaticContainer
                in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
                in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
                in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
                in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
                in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
                in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
                in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
                in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
                in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
                in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
                in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
                in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
                in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
                in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
                in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
                in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                in View (at Card.tsx:538)
                in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
                in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:620)
                in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
                in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:613)
                in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
                in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:495)
                in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
                in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
                in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:76)
                in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
                in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
                in GestureHandlerRootView (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.tsx:26)
                in GestureHandlerRootView (at StackView.tsx:454)
                in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
                in StackNavigator (at App.js:39)
                in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
                in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
                in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
                in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:38)
                in App (created by ExpoRoot)
                in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
                in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
                in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
                in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

            at node_modules\react-
            at [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5321:31 in runWithPriority$argument_1
            at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5316:21 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5304:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
            at node_modules\react-
            at [native code]:null in dispatchAction
            at node_modules\@react-navigation\core\src\useSyncState.tsx:38:9 in React.useCallback$argument_0
            at http://192.168.1.102:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:138144:20 in <unknown>
            at node_modules\@react-navigation\core\src\useNavigationHelpers.tsx:43:21 in dispatch
            at node_modules\@react-navigation\core\src\useNavigationCache.tsx:77:12 in dispatch
            at node_modules\@react-navigation\core\src\useNavigationCache.tsx:89:24 in acc.name
            at screens\LoginScreen.js:19:6 in onLogin
            at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
            at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
            at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
            at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
            at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
            at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
            at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
            at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
            at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

            Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:173:8 in registerError
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
            at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
        setImmediate$argument_0
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
            at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
            at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
            at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

I have done everything the resources have said so i added this:

```
      import React from 'react';
      import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
      import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
      import {View, StyleSheet, Alert, PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';

      import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
      import CallScreen from './screens/CallScreen';
      import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

      const Stack = createStackNavigator();

      const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
        try {
          const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
            {
              title: "Cool Photo App Camera Permission",
              message:
                "Cool Photo App needs access to your camera " +
                "so you can take awesome pictures.",
              buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
              buttonNegative: "Cancel",
              buttonPositive: "OK"
            }
          );
          if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            console.log("You can use the camera");
          } else {
            console.log("Camera permission denied");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.warn(err);
        }
      };

      const App = () => {

        requestCameraPermission();

        return (
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Login"
                component={LoginScreen}
                options={{headerShown: false}}
              />
              <Stack.Screen name="Call" component={CallScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        );
      };

      export default App;
```

And the resource i follwed was here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-incall-manager

Comment: It looks to me like react-native-incall-manager isn't installed properly. Double check that you've followed the installation procedures correctly on the native side

Comment: @Kai, thanks for the feedback, i deleted the Incal Manger folder from node modules, restarted my pc then npm the incall manager again and still get this error, any more clues?

Comment: There are some extra installation steps for iOS, and on Android, you'll want to double check that your build files have the right lines from the autolinking step. The readme has all of that info

Comment: @Kai, i have updated the question. still can get this to work, keeps saying incallmanager.checkrequestpermission and camera still showing a warning, any ideas?